Filtering polygons by name in one column of QGIS Attribute Table
I have a file geodatabase of the ranges of every bird species on Earth, but I am only interested in a subset of 538 of them for which I have data relevant to a study on sexual dichromatism.
The attribute table of the Attribute Table of this file geodatabase includes a variable called sci_name, which includes the scientific name of every bird species. I have a csv of all the scientific names of the birds I am interested in.
How do I filter the file geodatabase in QGIS to only include species listed in that csv?
I am not sure how to import that CSV into QGIS since it doesn't include any geographic data, but otherwise as far as I can tell I would have to filter the ESRI file geodatabase one species name at a time.
When I have tried to filter, just including one species, as follows
"sci_name" IN "Meliphaga analoga"

I get the following error:

An error occurred when executing the query. The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected
identifier, expecting '('. Occurred around : "sci_name" IN "Meliphaga
analoga"
^


The expression is syntactically incorrect: string literals should be enclosed by single quotes, not double quotes; the SQL IN operator is usually used to specify multiple values and should be followed by the list of values separated by commas enclosed in round brackets.
If you want to select only one value, then you just need to use:
"sci_name" = 'Meliphaga analoga'

the correct syntax using the SQL IN operator (although it is not necessary to use it since you want to filter only one value), would be:
"sci_name" IN ('Meliphaga analoga')

There are various way to "filter" the features in a layer based on a table imported from a csv file.
For example, you can:

import the CSV file containing the list of unique species names (i.e. assuming it doesn't contain repetitions) as a geometryless table by just dragging & dropping it in QGIS
set a join on the layer containing the data with the table based on the corresponding fields with the species names, ensuring that the "Joined fields" option is set and the field of the joined table containing the list of species is selected

Then, if the layer containing the data is a vector layer and you want to display on the map only the features' geometries of the species listed in the joined table, you can set the symbology of such layer as "Rule-based" and set the rule's as "joined_field" is not NULL replacing joined_field with the actual name of the joined field.
Or, if you want to actually have a layer containing only the records of the species listed in the joined table, then you can either:

set a "Filter" (which will automatically create a "Virtual layer" since the layer is joined to the table) and use the expression "joined_field" is not NULL replacing joined_field with the actual name of the joined field

or use the processing algorithm "Extract by expression" to create a new layer, setting the "Expression" parameter with the same expression mentioned above

or you can also avoid to set a join (or removing it if previously set) and directly create a "Virtual Layer" with the following SQL command:
select * from layer_name
join table_name
where layer_name.sci_name = table_name.table_field


replacing layer_name with the actual name of the layer, table_name with the actual name of the table, table_field with the actual name of the field of the table containing the species name.

Thanks! I used one value as an example, but is there a way to filter with a list of values which I have saved as a csv?

I've updated the answer.

This is a fairly simple task and the perfect use case for Python if you are up for trying a PyQGIS solution. The advantage here is that you don't even need to load your csv file into QGIS, you can just read it in with Python's csv module.
Open the QGIS's Python Console (Ctrl+Alt+P), open a blank editor (via the notebook icon) and paste in the script below.
You will need to edit the first 4 lines (see comments in the script to help you), and click Run (green 'play' button).
import csv

# You will need to change the 4 lines below
lyr_name = 'Bird_species'# This is the name of your layer loaded in QGIS which you want to filter
fld_name = 'sci_name'# This is the name of the field on which you are filtering

file_path = '/example/path/to/species.csv'# Full path to .csv file
sp_column_name = 'Species Name'# header of the csv column containing species of interest

csv_file = open(file_path)
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
species_names = []
row_count = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    if row_count == 0:
        sp_col_idx = row.index(sp_column_name)
    else:
        species_names.append(row[sp_col_idx])
    row_count+=1
csv_file.close()

lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_name)[0]
lyr.setSubsetString(f'"{fld_name}" IN {tuple(species_names)}')

See image below:


You can import your csv as an non geographic table by choosing the  No geometry option in the Geometry Definition section in the delimited text data manager window as shown below

Also note that filter window in QGIS only works on the layer attributes alone and does not allow input from other layers when building the filter expression. So to filter the birds you ate interested in, I suggest you list all the scientific names of the birds you are interested in, separated by commas enclosed in round brackets.
"sci_name" IN ('Meliphaga analoga', 'name 2',... ,'last name')

